# Unable to setup flutter for web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I try to execute command: `flutter channel beta` I get the below error:

```
Switching to flutter channel 'beta'...
git: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/': error setting certificate verify 
locations:  CAfile: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.cert CApath: none
Switching channels failed with error code 128.
```

One of the SO solutions suggested I use the command: `git config --system http.sslcainfo 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt'`, but this did not change the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Make sure you have installed latest version of git, and please do not use image to display the error - this prevents other users from using the message in their search query.

Comment: @Spatz, thanks for the input. I have replaced the image. Also, my git is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was not with flutter, but with git. Flutter uses git for its commands and git was not able to locate the certificate file. What worked for me was:

1. Visit https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git/
2. View the certificate from the address bar and save it ( lets say as poc.cer )
3. Add this certificate to git config using : git config --global http.sslCAInfo "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\poc.cer"

Now the commands work without any issue